# How to Load page content to div with select box in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to load page content into a div via Ajax when a select option is selected.

This is my code, but it will not work.

```js
$('mySelect').on('change',function(){
 function loadPage(url){
  $("#page").load(url);
}
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <div class="container">
  <select class="custom-select" id="mySelect">
  <option value="1" onchange="loadPage('One.html')">One</option>
  <option value="2" onchange="loadPage('Two.html')">Two</option>
  </select>
 </div>
  
  <div id="page"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

I have a select box with 2 options the values are One.html and Two.html and under that I have a div and want the content from One.html and Two.html to load in the div when the select box changes... Via Ajax any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Why not create an iframe and set its `src` attribute as per need (as opposed to getting the page through AJAX)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the id sign `#` :

```
$('mySelect').on('change',function(){
```

Should be :

```
$('#mySelect').on('change',function(){
___^
```

Try to avoid the inline event `onchange()` and use `data-*` to store the `url` param then pass it to the `loadPage` function inside the change event.

```js
$(function() {
  loadPage("One.html");

  $('#mySelect').on('change', function() {
    loadPage($(this).find(':selected').data('url'));
    //OR
    // $("#page").load( $(this).find(':selected').data('url') );
  });
});

function loadPage(url) {
  $("#page").load(url);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <select class="custom-select" id="mySelect">
    <option value="1" data-url="One.html">One</option>
    <option value="2" data-url="Two.html">Two</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="page"></div>
```

Comment: His code is working. Check here https://jsfiddle.net/qu8r8nLj/2/ @Nguyễn

Comment: @Irfan TahirKheli Thank you!
How to default load One.html?

Answer (score 3):

it's quite simple:

```js
$("#SelectOne").change(function() {
    $("#someDiv").load($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<select id="SelectOne">
    <option>One.html</option>
    <option>Two.html</option>
</select>

<div id="someDiv"></div>
```